# Временное сохранение объектов в SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

На сколько это правильно, сохранять объекты в SP (объект перевожу в gson и сохраняю как строка)?
В приложении я из фрагмента перехожу в активити и мне надо сохранить 3 объекта, которые создались в фрагменте, а когда я обратно возвращаюсь в фрагмент из активити, получить эти объекты.

Может имеется более простой способ сохранения объектов?

Comment: Сохранять объекты в SP можно по идее, но я думаю в вашем случае это лишнее. По идее объекты из фрагмента в активити можно с помощью метода-геттера. Покажите кусок кода, так будет понятнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам надо сохранить состояние фрагмента между его показами, вы должны переопределить метод фрагмента `onSaveInstanceState`. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(FIRST_OBJECT_KEY, firstObject);
    outState.putSerializable(SECOND_OBJECT_KEY, secondObject);
}
```

Сохраненные таким образом данные, вы затем можете получить в методе фрагмента `onCreate` из его параметра `savedInstanceState`, вот так:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(FIRST_OBJECT_KEY)){
        firstObject = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(FIRST_OBJECT_KEY);
    } else {
        // значит ничего не было сохранено ранее, 
        // то есть видимо фрагмент еще ни разу не создавался
    }
}
```